# Apply a linq expression of an object to a list of items where that object is a propery of an item (Wrapper)

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I need to be able to apply an expression of a property to a wrapper of that property, below is an example; a list of numbers and a list wrapper numbers where the expression is [where numbers are even]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ExpressionTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /* Expression */
            Expression<Func<int, bool>> expression = item => item % 2 == 0;


            /* List */
            IList<int> items = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                items.Add(i);
            }
            IEnumerable<int> evenNumbers = items.Where(expression.Compile());
            foreach (int number in evenNumbers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(number.ToString());
            }


            /* Wrappers List */
            // How to apply expression to the porpery 'Number'?
            IList<Wrapper> wrappers = new List<Wrapper>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                wrappers.Add(new Wrapper { Number = i });
            }
            IEnumerable<int> evenWrappedNumbers = ????; 
            foreach (Wrapper wrappedNumber in evenWrappedNumbers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(wrappedNumber.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public class Wrapper
    {
        public int Number;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Func<int, bool> predicate = expression.Compile();
IEnumerable<Wrapper> evenWrappedNumbers = wrappers.Where(w => predicate(w.Number));
```

Or if you do want an `IEnumerable<int>`

```
Func<int, bool> predicate = expression.Compile();
IEnumerable<int> evenWrappedNumbers = wrappers.Where(w => predicate(w.Number)).Select(w => w.Number);
```

Edit: Since learning that NHibernate is in use, here is another possible solution. Please bear in mind, I don't use NHibernate and have limited experience with expression trees. But none the less, this should hopefully allow NHibernate to parse the expression tree to SQL.

First define an extension method in a static class like so:

```
    public static IQueryable<T> Where<T, TProperty>(this IQueryable<T> source,
        Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> propertySelector,
        Expression<Func<TProperty, bool>> predicate)
    {
        MemberExpression member = propertySelector.Body as MemberExpression;

        if (member == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Must be a property selector", "propertySelector");

        string propertyName = member.Member.Name;

        // The input type
        ParameterExpression propertyParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

        // The property on that type
        MemberExpression itemProperty = Expression.Property(propertyParameter, propertyName);

        // Invoke the specified predicate with the property from the input type
        InvocationExpression invokeExpression = Expression.Invoke(predicate, itemProperty);

        // The lambda expression for use with Linq
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> finalExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(invokeExpression, propertyParameter);

        return source.Where(finalExpression);
    }
```

Then this extension method can be utilised like so:

```
    IEnumerable<Wrapper> evenWrappedNumbers = wrappers.Where(w => w.Number, expression);
```

As I say, I have no experience with NHibernate, but hopefully it should be able to parse this expression tree and convert it to SQL.

Comment: Is there a way of not compiling it? because i intend to pass it to NHibernate as a linq expression, cannot have it as a compiled function.

Comment: `Func<int, bool> predicate = new Func<int, bool>(item => item % 2 == 0);`, like that?

Comment: This won't work with NHibernate as it cannot execute .net functions (predicate) on DB, it can only analyze the expression back to be able to construct a query to DB, the final expression must be something like (x => x.Number % 2 == 0), except that i need the "inner" expression to be passed dynamically.

Comment: @user997923 Since discovering that you use NHibernate, I have updated my example with a possible solution, it should work by building up an expression tree rather than compiled statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways that don't use expression.  I'm guessing you want Lukazoid's solution.

```
    Expression<Func<Wrapper, bool>> expressionNew = item => item.Number % 2 == 0;
```

and this:

```
    IEnumerable<int> evenWrappedNumbers = wrappers.Where(item => item.Number % 2 == 0);
```